# Can't connect my static javascript file to socket.io library in NodeJS and ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, debugging, socket.io

I am creating an app using nodejs, expressjs and
This is my index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const router = require("./controller/routes");
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  path: "/socket.io", // Add this line to specify the path
});
port = 4000;

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use("/", router.router);
app.use(
  "/socket.io",
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/socket.io/client-dist"))
);

app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("A user connected");

  socket.on("join-room", () => {
    console.log("Joined the room");
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("User disconnected");
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

And I have configured sockets in my .ejs file. I am emitting an event from my script.js and my console inside io.on() is not printing.

My script.js inside public folder.

```
const socket = io();
const videoGrid = document.getElementById("video-grid");
console.log(videoGrid);
const myVideo = document.createElement("video");
myVideo.muted = true;

let myVideoStream;

navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true,
  })
  .then((stream) => {
    myVideoStream = stream;
    addVideoStream(myVideo, stream);
    socket.emit("join-room");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Error accessing media devices: ", err);
  });
```

Expecting my console to get printed

Comment: Can you share your ejs file. Make sure you included this tag
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
and this <script src="/public/script.js"></script>
in ejs

Comment: Yes I have included both of the files. 
I am using router and my routes are at a different location. Can that be a issue?
'/create-room' This is the route that renders the ejs file.